# RabbitMQ access refused when publishing message - how to give user permission for specific queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I've setup a very basic queue, 'test_queue', on a fresh installation of RabbitMQ, and created a basic non-admin user, 'user' (which I have given the same virtual host access as admin account).

When I send in a test message on the command line via:

```
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=amq.default routing_key=test_queue payload="hello, world" -u admin -p {admin password}
```

It works just fine. But when I try and use the basic user:

```
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=amq.default routing_key=test_queue payload="hello, world" -u user -p {user password}
```

I get the following error:

> *** Access refused: /api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish

I've searched for how to add permission for a specific user to publish to a message queue but can't find the solution through the noise.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by adding the permission through RabbitMQ Admin UI (Admin->Users->Some User->Set Permission):
[image]
You can enable the Admin UI as a plugin through CLI:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

To access it you will also need to create some login credentials.
More details: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#getting-started

Answer (score -2):

I searched Google with `site:rabbitmq.com permission` and this document is the first hit: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

At the end of the ["How Permissions Work"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions) section, you are directed to the [`rabbitmqctl` man page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html)

Within that page, you will find the documentation for the [`set_permissions`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#set_permissions) command. That is what you need to use.

If you would like to open a pull request to improve the documentation to make finding this solution easier, we would welcome it [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-website)! Thanks.